# Seek advise on Income Tax for India and US - for a new Green Card Holder

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india

1. No income in US till date.
2. Have some income in India - interest on FDs and Rental income.

Please advise:

1. how and where to Fill the forms in US? What all to declare (about India income) and how?
2. Should I continue paying taxes in India as before? Do i have to mention change of my status to NRI?
3. Should I change my Indian bank accounts to NRI - as FDs are there?
4. Any other advise on this please.

Thanks & Regards